# Paste event doesn't work on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, paste

On IE11 paste events throws an exception when calling services from different modules within the same `paste` context.

Basically when you call method using `click` event it works, but with `paste` event exception is thrown.

## Repro

- Step 1
  Add (paste) event on template element `(paste)="onPaste()`

  `<input (paste)="onPaste()" />`

  or add `HostListener`

  `@HostListener('paste', [])
  onPaste() {
      await this.service.Do();
  }`
- Step 2
  Paste anything into the input field.

  link to a sample repo: https://github.com/brivvirs/angularclipastebug

#### Observed behavior

Throws an exception on IE11

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid argument.
...`

#### Versions

`Angular CLI: 1.6.6
Node: 8.1.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.2`

Not sure whether `cli` is missing polyfills or its a global angular issue.
Also IE11 supports paste event.
https://caniuse.com/#search=paste

Comment: IE11 doesn't support await though » https://caniuse.com/#search=await

Comment: it works flawlessly for me

Comment: I have enabled polyfills so async functions should work on IE11.
@RahulSingh Did you clone my project and it works? Can you share `ng --version`?

Comment: i didnot clone it actually just created a new project for the same

Comment: In my provided example it fails to call `http` service. 
https://github.com/brivvirs/angularclipastebug/blob/master/src/app/base.service.ts#L8

But it's not the only case where it dies.
`onPaste` method is called properly.